# SharePoint 2013 connection to OpenLdap web.config

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How correct configure openLdap?

Have you got any idea where I made mistake?

**I Get this from Admin:**

ldaps://auth-01.domein.srv"
cn=ldapreader,ou=Technical,o=domein.net.pl,dc=domein,dc=srv

Password: JPnds2222dd

In web.config I try make this (I added membership):

```
<membership defaultProvider="i">
      <providers>
        <add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
        <add name="membership"
    type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LDAPMembershipProvider,Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
    server="ldaps.auth-01.domain.srv"
    port="389"
    useSSL="false"
    connectionUsername="cn=ldapreader,ou=Technical,o=domein.net.pl,dc=domein,dc=srv"
    connectionPassword= "JPnds2222dd"
    useDNAttribute="false"
    userNameAttribute="uid"
    userContainer="ou=Technical,dc=domein,dc=srv"
    userObjectClass="person"
    userFilter="(objectClass=person)"
    scope="Subtree"
    otherRequiredUserAttributes="uid,cn" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="c" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <add name="c" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ee806890.aspx